# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Urls.MeaningfulURL, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This question is specific to taking in a formatted url value and comparing to an unformatted database value.

I have a url /companies/my-company/

The company's name is stored in the database field as "My Company" - note: no hyphen, space and uppercase.

It could be stored in an even more complex format  like "John's Company >>" because the user has the ability to input this in the CMS.

So how do I compare my-company to My Company in LINQ to Entites?

```
var type = Context.Set<Domain.Content.Organisation>()
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Select(x => new DataContracts.Content.Organisation
                        {
                            Id = x.Id
                            ,Name = x.Name
                            ,OrganisationTypeId = x.OrganisationTypeId
                            ,OrganisationTypeName = (x.OrganisationType != null) ? x.OrganisationType.Name : string.Empty
                            ,Categories = x.Categories.Select(i => i.Id)
                            ,IsCustomer = x.IsCustomer
                            ,CountryId = x.CountryId
                            ,CountryName = (x.Country != null) ? x.Country.Name : string.Empty,
                            SeoName = x.SeoName,
                            Description = x.Description,                           
                            Website = x.Website
                        })
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id || Urls.MeaningfulURL(x.SeoName.ToLower(), null) == seoName.ToLower());
```

The problem here is:

```
Urls.MeaningfulURL(x.SeoName.ToLower(), null) == seoName.ToLower()
```

It generates an error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Urls.MeaningfulURL method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I understand what it means, but cannot figure out a way around it.

Urls.MeaningfulURL is a method that does a lot of string replacements to create the url format 'my-company'.

How can I format column x.SeoName at query time correctly so it matches my url input ?

Thanks

Comment: you can not use other functions in LINQ

Comment: Can you add to your database table computable column that will calculate MeaningfulUrl? Or may be you can create view that will return MeaningfulUrl?

Comment: Yes, i think this will have to be done at a database level with a computed column, view or stored procedure. I was hoping it would be possible in LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF cann't translate `Urls.MeaningfulURL` to SQL. There are so many options to resolve it:

**1. Load data first:**

```
var type = Context.Set<Domain.Content.Organisation>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(your select)
    .ToList()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id || Urls.MeaningfulURL(x.SeoName.ToLower(), null) == seoName.ToLower());
```

it's simplest but it produces perfomance problems cause all `Organisation` will be loaded from db into memory.

**2. Rewrite your logic.**

You cann't apply custom method to `x.SeoName` so just don't do that. Try to rewrite your query to:

```
var type = Context.Set<Domain.Content.Organisation>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(your select)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id || computedString.Contains(x.SeoName));
```

And yes, you can use `Contains`, at least for SQL Server provider.

**3. Move your logic to SQL:**

If SQL Server is used, you can try computed column, view, and even [CLR code on SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx) etc.

**4. Store the computed value in db:**

Sometimes it is better to store `Urls.MeaningfulURL(x.SeoName.ToLower(), null)` value instead or together with `x.SeoName` and use this stored value in queries. Also it becomes possible to add an index on this field.

Comment: I would be interested in option 2. However x.seoname could be any format. And the URL input is already formatted. So computedString.Contains will not work, as computedString is already formatted. Do you agree?   I think Option 3 is what i will have to go for.

Comment: @fourbeatcoder, it's hard to say without examples of `x.seoname` values and `Urls.MeaningfulURL` logic. Sometimes it's even better to change db schema to store computed  `Urls.MeaningfulURL(x.SeoName.ToLower(), null)` instead of raw `x.SeoName` (I think I should add this option to answer).

Comment: Yes, option 4 is also viable. Thank you.